# CSS: Make image height of viewport while keeping width 100% and cropping edges if wider than viewport

Tags: css, image

I want to create a responsive image that takes up the entire height off the viewport and scales as the viewport changes.

I know that I can set the height with this:

```
height: 100vmax;
```

However, I cannot understand how to get the image width to change and effectively crop it's edges off so that the image stays centred horizontally.

A great example of is [Big Green Egg's website](https://www.biggreenegg.co.uk) although they use a video and I want to use an image.

It's worth mentioning that I need to enter this code into a CMS page (Magento 2) so it will sit within a set of other DIVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "vh" and use text-align on the outer container to center the image:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://kingofwallpapers.com/sexy-girl-wallpapers/sexy-girl-wallpapers-002.jpg">
```

But I would recommend to use background-image instead, since it's a part of design, not a content:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #e0eaec url(http://eskipaper.com/images/mikako-zhang-5.jpg) no-repeat center center / auto 100%;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>&lt;header&gt; goes here</h1>
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: I can see that this clearly works in your example and I've tried this approach before but it doesn't work for me. I'm trying to put this into a Magento CMS page and as a result, it's already within a set of other DIVs so I can't use body but even so, it doesn't seem to work in my CMS page using a DIV. e.g. <div style="text-align: center;">
     <img style="height: 100vh;" src="Url/home/bespoke_glasses_frame.png" alt="test">
</div>

Comment: Try this one maybe: "<div style="text-align: center; height: 100vh;"><img style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top;" src="/home/bespoke_glasses_frame.png"></div>", but actually you have to update your question with non-working example so that we can see the actual problem.

Comment: Whatever I try, it always just stretches the image down (rather than cropping off the edges) if the resulting image would need to be wider than the viewport. However, if the image width is less than the viewport relative to the depth, then it scales down perfectly (centring nicely). What it won't do, is expand wider than the enclosing DIV (cropping off the edges) and keep the image ratio correct.

Comment: Here is my code using a panoramic picture https://jsfiddle.net/hxakbg2z/ everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go very simple here, with a css solution based on adding only `object-fit` and an optional `object-position`, very useful when the main point for adjustment is not the center of the picture

html

```
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518453850752-056b15f0a4ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
```

css

```
img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 75% 75%;
}
```

Try to reduce the width of the picture in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b42uhat8/): you will see that the focus will keep always around the dome. I suggest also to read [this gem](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/)

By default, `object-position: 50% 50%` [i.e. the center of the picture] so in this case you don't need to specify it

NOTE - you can check their support on different browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)